# How to pass an argument to a TRACE32 .mem file?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to implement a "generic" TRACE32 menu that takes a parameter and can be reused across different projects.

Would something like that be possible? How do I pass an argument to a `.mem` file loaded by `MENU.ReProgram`?

```
;my_menu.mem
ADD
MENU
(
    POPUP "&User"
    (
        DEFAULT
        MENUITEM "Disable watchdog"
        (
            DO ~~~~/boards/&board/disable_wdg.cmm
            ;              ^^^^^^
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the menu into a PRACTICE script as an embedded menu block. Start the block with `&+` to enable macro replacement in the embedded block.

You can pass the parameters for the menu to the embedding script using the `PARAMETERS` keyword.

Note: You can not use `~~~~/` in a menu command. `~~~~/` means path of currently executed PRACTICE script. At the time the menu command is executed, most likely the script is no longer running, and the value of `~~~~/` is not valid anymore.

Example:

```
;my_menu.cmm
LOCAL      &rootpath &user &board
PARAMETERS &rootpath &user &board

MENU.ReProgram
(&+
  ADD
  MENU
  (
    POPUP "&user"
    (
      DEFAULT
      MENUITEM "Disable watchdog"
      (
        DO "&rootpath/boards/&board/disable_wdg.cmm"
      )
    )
  )
)
ENDDO
```

Call with e.g.:

```
DO d:\my_menu.cmm "/home/user/t32" "MyName" "MyBoardName"
```